# HadoopStreaming R as reducer Fail

Tags: python, r, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am writing a hadoop streaming job where the mappers are simple data cleaning written in Python and in the reducer part I want to run certain time series analysis using R. However, it is really not that easy to debug mapreduce job itself and I ended up writing my reducer in a way that recognize what is the key and value and then write them out to the result unmodified. However, it is still not working and my python code which does exactly the same thing works without problem.

When the streaing job using R as reducer, the error message looks like this:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1 
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320) at     
org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533) at 
org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134) at 
org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
 javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at     
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554) at
```

org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

I am running this streaming job on a cluster of 4 data nodes (64GB mem each) and it spawned about 500 mappers and 60 reducers in total. My reducer code in both languages are posted. Any suggestion or help is appreicated!

This is the reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
delimiter = '\t'

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    mykey, myvalue = line.split(delimiter)
    print delimiter.join([mykey, myvalue])
```

This is the reducer.R

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(dplyr)
library(outliers)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)
#library(tsoutliers)

f <- file("stdin")
open(f, open="r")
options(warn=-1)

mydelimiter <- '\t'

sink('/dev/null')
while(length(line<-readLines(f, n=1)) > 0){
    tryCatch(
        {
            line <- gsub('\n', '', line)
            fields <- unlist(strsplit(line, split=mydelimiter))
            mykey_new <- fields[1]
            myvalue_new <- fields[2]
            sink()
            cat(mykey_new);cat(mydelimiter);cat(myvalue_new);cat('\n')
            sink('/dev/null')
        },
        error=function(e){}
    )
}

close(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The java error you are getting just tells you that running the program failed but it doesn't tell you what the problem was in the program. To see that you need to get the the stderr logs from your container.

If you go to your jobtracker page (something like http://myserver.com:50030/jobtracker.jsp) and find your failed job you can click on the number in the 'failed tasks' column and get to the task logs from there. You should be able to find the problem there.